# Why is Python Regex Wildcard only matching newLine

Tags: python, regex, wildcard, logfile

I am writing a program to parse through log messages using Python RegEx.  I've gotten everything situated up until the message of the log.  This could be any number of types of characters so I'm assuming the .* wildcard symbol would be the best solution for this problem. It matches everything except for a new line.

However, when I'm using the wildcard the only thing returning is the new line in this instance.  Any ideas?  Here's the code and the output:

```
import os
import re
#Change to and print correct file path
os.chdir('/Users/MacUser/Desktop/regExPython')
print(os.getcwd())

#Iterate and read from syslogexample.txt then print results
line_number = 0
with open('syslogexample.txt', 'r') as syslog:
    log_lines = syslog.readlines()
    for line in log_lines:
        line_number += 1
        print('{:>4} {}'.format(line_number, line.rstrip()))


#Build regex to parse through the data
DATE_RE = r'(\w{3}\s+\d{2})'
TIME_RE = r'(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})'
DEVICE_RE = r'(\S+)'
PROCESS_RE = r'(\S+\s+\S+:)'
MESSAGE_RE = r'(.*)'
CD_RE = r'(\s+)'

Syslog_RE = DATE_RE + CD_RE + \
            TIME_RE + CD_RE + \
            DEVICE_RE + CD_RE + \
            PROCESS_RE + CD_RE + \
            MESSAGE_RE

#Use regex to parse through the data
for line in log_lines:
    m = re.match(Syslog_RE, line)
    if m:
        print(m.groups())

#Printed log Files
      1 apr 29 08:22:13 mac-users-macbook-8 syslogd[49]: asl sender statistics
   2 apr 29 08:22:17 mac-users-macbook-8 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.system):
   3 service "com.apple.emond.aslmanager" tried to hijack endpoint "com.apple.aslmanager" from owner:
   4 com.apple.aslmanager
   5 apr 29 08:22:17 mac-users-macbook-8 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.system):
   6 service "com.apple.emond.aslmanager" tried to hijack endpoint
   7 "com.apple.activity_tracing.cache-delete" from owner: com.apple.aslmanager
   8 apr 29 08:22:17 mac-users-macbook-8 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[14184]):
   9 endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) apis. please switch to xpc or
  10 bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
  11 apr 29 08:22:19 mac-users-macbook-8 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]
  12 (com.apple.imfoundation.imremoteurlconnectionagent): unknown key for integer:
  13 _dirtyjetsammemorylimit

Parsed Log Files
('apr 29', ' ', '08:22:17', ' ', 'mac-users-macbook-8', ' ', 'com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.system):', '\n', '')
('apr 29', ' ', '08:22:17', ' ', 'mac-users-macbook-8', ' ', 'com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.system):', '\n', '')
('apr 29', ' ', '08:22:17', ' ', 'mac-users-macbook-8', ' ', 'com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[14184]):', '\n', '')

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you can see at the end where MESSAGE_RE is the only printed characters are the \n newline characters which I thought wouldn't be printing at all.

Thanks all!

Comment: The `'\n'`s are matches for CD_RE, MESSAGE_RE is always producing `''` since there's nothing left in the line.  Since you're only looking at a single line at a time, and the messages are always on separate lines, there's no possibility of MESSAGE_RE ever matching anything.

Comment: The problem is that each log like can be split in any number of lines of text. That's weird because in every logging system that I know (Apple included), there's always one message per line. If you can get the logs in the original form, that's the cleanest solution.
If you absolutely need to do multiline matches with your regexes, look at [`re.S`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.S)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in http://www.regex101.com the regex does not work correctly because `.*` only captures *until* newline character, meaning at the linebreak from i.e. line 3 to 4 it stops matching. maybe try `re.compile()` and compile the regex before `re.match()`. in python regex module there is the `DOTALL` flag that enables `.` to match newline characters as well  http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html